# Using Riemann's methods to derive the floor function of x from the zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, riemann-zeta

I thought it would be interesting to try and use Riemann's methods to derive (rather than the quantity of primes less than $x$) the quantity of natural numbers less than $x$. This function is, of course, the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$.
First we write the definition for the Zeta function:
\[\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}\]
\[\frac{1}{n^s}=s\int_n^\infty x^{-s-1}dx\]
\[\implies\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_n^\infty x^{-s-1}dx\]
\[\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}=\int_0^\infty F(x)x^{-s-1}dx\]
See that the function $F(x)$ has jumps at each whole number, which means that
$F(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\leq0\\\lfloor x\rfloor&0<x\notin\mathbb{N}\\\lfloor x \rfloor-0.5&x\in\mathbb{N}\end{cases}$

Now by substitution of $x=e^{t}$
\[\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(e^{t})e^{-st}dt\]
Which is a Laplace transform, meaning it can be inverted by
\[F(e^{t})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}e^{st}ds\]
Now by reverting the substitution $t=ln(x)$
\[F(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}x^sds\]
Now taking the residue at the two poles of the function $s=1$ and $s=0$ we find that $Res(\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}x^s,1)=x$ and $Res(\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}x^s,0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ which means that $F(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}$ which is a good approximation, but is not the exact value of this function, which is what i was expecting. Can anybody tell me what went wrong in these steps.

Comment: What went wrong is that you wrote down an expression (an integral over a non-closed contour) and then computed a second expression (the sum of two residues) without ever establishing how the two expressions should be related to each other.

Comment: @GregMartin but its a closed contour right? The line integral in the inverse laplace transform is a closed contour? What should i do to close this contour?

Comment: there are a few issues - first $\int_0^\infty F(x)x^{-s-1}dx$ doesn't distinguish between the values of $F$ at any zero measure set, so it's irrelevant what $F$ is on the integers; second you didn't write where the inversion formula is true; it is actually true only for $\Re s >1$ by the general theory and third when you pass to the left of zero as you did it doesn't mean that the result is exact since there is no reason for the integral there to vanish;

Comment: An infinite vertical line is not a closed contour.

Comment: @Conrad what do you mean by the last part? What integral doesnt vanish and what do you mean by pass left of zero?

Comment: The integral representation for $F$ you have is valid for $\Re \gamma>1$ only as is easy to see in various ways; using Cauchy as usual you can move the abscissa to the left passing through poles at $1$ and $0$ so getting that $F$ is $x-1/2$ plus the same integral now with $\Re \gamma <0$; however the integral there doesn't vanish and the result hence is not exact;

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between the floor function representation

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \theta(x-n)\right),\quad x\ge 0\tag{1}$$

(where $\theta(x)$ is the Heavide step function) and the Dirichlet series

$$\zeta(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{2}$$

for the Riemann zeta function is the term-wise Mellin and inverse Mellin transforms

$$s\, \mathcal{M}_x[\theta(x-n)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty \theta(x-n)\, x^{-s}\, dx=s \int\limits_n^\infty x^{-s}\, dx=\frac{1}{n^s}\tag{3}$$

and

$$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}\, \frac{1}{s}\right]\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\int\limits_{\beta-i \infty}^{\beta+i \infty} \frac{1}{n^s}\, \frac{x^s}{s}\, ds=\theta(x-n)\tag{4}$$

---

Also, the Fourier series representation

$$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(\frac{1}{\pi} \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{\sin(2 k \pi x)}{k}\right)\tag{5}$$

for the function

$$f(x)=\underset{\epsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}} \left(\frac{\lfloor x-\epsilon \rfloor +\lfloor x+\epsilon \rfloor}{2}\right)\tag{6}$$

which converges to $\lfloor x \rfloor$ except at integer values of $x$ can be derived from the inverse Mellin transform

$$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}\right]\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\int\limits_{\alpha -i \infty}^{\alpha+i \infty}  \zeta(s)\, \frac{x^s}{s}\, ds\,,\quad \alpha<0\tag{7}$$

where the inverse Mellin transform integral in formula (7) above is evaluated term-wise from the representation

$$\zeta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(2^s\, \pi^{s-1}\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\, \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{1}{k^{1-s}}\right),\quad\Re(s)<0\tag{8}.$$

The result of the inverse Mellin transform integral in formula (7) above corresponds to the sum over $k$ in formula (5) above, but one must also account for the residues of $\zeta(s)\, \frac{x^s}{s}$ at $s=1$ and $s=0$ which correspond to the $x$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ terms in formula (5) above.